# Machine Learning - Which approach fits best to predict discrete,continuous solutions from features of various importance?

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection

I need to come up with a formula that takes up to N inputs and calculates a single number that should predict the "correct" answer as often as possible. Each input is a decimal value or integer. The output is also a decimal value.

I have an absurd amount of data (consider it infinite). In each case I have the value of all of the inputs and the correct value of the output.

The features are all inter-related (i.e. when one is high another is more likely to be low) and they have differing degrees of relevance to the answer.

There is no "perfect" formula but there should be one that holds true in many statistically significant cases. If I had a "best" solution it would likely be both non-linear and discrete. This is, however, a one-time computation.

What machine learning solution is best for taking these kinds of features and creating an accurate-ish model to represent such complicated, somewhat-random data?

Edit: Doing some more research it appears that any kind of linear regression will fail. Neural networks look like the best choice but I don't know if they can predict this "discrete" function that has different formulas in different ranges.

Answer (score 5):

Having a near infinite amount of training and testing data is a huge advantage.  Linear regression *is* unlikely to be useful for the irregular function you describe, but before writing it off completely you may want to look at regression on derived features rather than on the input itself.  Radial Bias Functions are sometimes useful in place of or in addition to your basic N inputs.

My advice however is to take a look at regression trees and particularly random forests.

Regression trees are basically decision trees which start at the root and make some comparison  on one of your N inputs to select a branch to follow.  This continues until you reach a leaf of the tree which has a linear model associated with it.  In the simplest case this may simply be a constant value function representing the average of data that winds up in that leaf, but more complex learning algorithms will attempt to select a linear model for the leaf which will minimize the expected square error at the leaf (such as ridge regression on some subset of the N input values).

The advantage of regression trees for your problem is that the tree divides your input into different regions in which a different formulas can be applied. With enough regions the linear functions can approximate very complex functions.

Regression trees do have some problems.  The behavior of the model near the decision boundaries defining your regions can take unrealistic jumps not supported by the data.  Additionally they can have some statistical problems.  Both of these problems are greatly alleviated through the use of random forests.

Each tree in a random forest is created by a unique bootstrap set of data. Normally this bootstrap set is created by taking a random sample with replacement from the training data but in your unique case you can improve this by taking a new random set of training data to create each tree in the forest.  Then in growing the tree, the decision variable that branches the tree at each node is restricted at that unique node to a random subset of the N variables.   Since each tree in the forest is created from a different data set and likely branches on different data, the weak points of the regression trees are distributed.  To make a prediction the input is given to each tree in the forest and the answer is obtained by averaging the results of all the trees.  This also sidesteps the statistical problems that regression trees can have.

Random forests are well regarded and are one of the better regression techniques for many test problems.

(See Elements of Statistical Learning: Data Mining, Inference and Prediction 2nd ed. - Trevor Hastie, Robert Tibshirani, Jerome Friedman, Springer 2008.)

Or for a bit narrower focus, the Microsoft technical report Decision Forests for Classication, Regression, Density Estimation, Manifold Learning and Semi-Supervised Learning, http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/155552/decisionForests_MSR_TR_2011_114.pdf